# Mono - Native UI on each platform?

Tags: user-interface, mono, xamarin, cross-platform, monodevelop

Is it possible to have one core dll written in mono and 3 separated native UIs on Linux, Mac and Windows? If yes, what are the options I have?

Let's assume I have written a GUI with WPF (Windows) and now I want to connect the mono dll to the WPF Form so I can use it's exported functions and classes. Same on Mac OS X: GUI written in Cocoa and connected to a mono core dll?

[image]

Do you guys know any example projects, which uses that approach?

Comment: Another approach would be wxWidgets, as it produces pure native UI, but .Net bindings isn't great for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a PCL library that contains your logic, combined with the Xamarin.Mac framework on OSX, GtkSharp on Linux, and WPF on Windows. As for using raw Cocoa, that'd be tougher; you'd have to host the Mono runtime (which is not impossible but also not easy).

Edit: I should add that you *could* also try for a "write once" UI and use GtkSharp for all three.

Comment: for the "write once" UI option, there's another alternative: https://github.com/mono/xwt/

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution: https://github.com/picoe/Eto

It does exactly what I was looking for!